# LEGO Dacta Intelligent House

Tags: software, dacta

I obtained an LEGO [Dacta 9707 Intelligent House](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9707-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) set plus the Interface B:

[image: https://img.bricklink.com/ItemImage/EXTN/3567.png?0]

By searching on BrickLink for the set, I found out that there was an Activity
Pack for use with Control Lab software.

If someone has the software and guide for DOS/WIN ([item 9708](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?B=9708#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)), please let me know ;)

[image: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?B=9708#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://archive.org/details/LegoDacta)?

Comment: Were you able to find the intelligent house 9708 or 9710 activity pack books?

Answer (score 4):

As mindstormsboi says, you can find it on archive.org
[here](https://archive.org/details/LegoDacta)